# How does Intent.ACTION_DIAL works in android tablets without GSM support

Tags: android

`Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);`

how does above intent or ACTION_DIAL works in tablets that does not support GSM.

Some pointers would be helpful.

thanks

Comment: How did you know that if works on Tablets without Phone?

Comment: An Samsung model tablet did not have any GSM connection, so they could not download the application.

Answer (score 0):

Some tablets have CDMA access. If you want to check for actual voice call abilities you best check the telephony manager:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getPhoneType